# Why p-values of chi-squared calculated through python library 'stats.chi2_contigency' is different from the p-value calculated through manual method

Tags: python, chi-squared-test

First I calculated the chi-squared p-value with

```
data = pd.crosstab(df['variable1'],df['variable2'])
chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(data)

print("Chi-squared statistic: ", chi2)
print("p-value: ", p)
```

*Chi-squared statistic:  70.23601804402738;
p-value:  2.893285699471121e-10;
Degree of Freedom:  12*

Then I tried to calculate it manually using the following code

```
data.values
observed_values = data.values
val = stats.chi2_contingency(data)
chisq_stat, pvalue, df, expected = chi2_contingency(observed_values)
expected_values = val[3]
no_of_rows=len(data.iloc[0:4,0])
no_of_columns=len(data.iloc[0,0:5])
ddof=(no_of_rows-1)*(no_of_columns-1)
print("Degree of Freedom:-",ddof)
alpha = 0.05
chi_square=sum([(o-e)**2/e for o,e in zip(observed_values,expected_values)])
chi_square_statistic=chi_square[0]+chi_square[1]
print(chi_square)
print("chi-square statistic:-",chi_square_statistic)
critical_value=chi2.ppf(q=1-alpha,df=ddof)
print('critical_value:',critical_value)
p_value=1-chi2.cdf(x=chi_square_statistic,df=ddof)
print('p-value:',p_value)
print('Significance level: ',alpha)
print('Degree of Freedom: ',ddof)
```

These are the results from the above code

*chi-square statistic:- 11.94630668094643;
critical_value: 21.02606981748307;
p-value: 0.45000142553796574;
Significance level:  0.05;
Degree of Freedom:  12*

**Where I am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

Please add a reproducible example for the data you are using.

The python function employs a continuity correction (adding 0.5 to each observation towards the expected). Try running it with:

```
scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(observed, correction=False)
```

It should return the correct answer. You can read more about it in the function documentation - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html

Comment: I think in manual method `chi_square_statistic=chi_square[0]+chi_square[1] ` is not adding statistics of all the 5 columns...Only adding adding two. I just replaced this line with `chi_square_statistic=chi_square.sum`...now both methods are producing same results...